# How to convert the wilcox.test W value output for two independent groups to U in R?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I need the U values of Mann-Whitney test, but the wilcox.test in R outputs only W values. I do not think they are identical, so here is my question - how to convert W to U?

Comment: The help for the function (`?wilcox.test`) makes it clear that the W that is calculated there is the same as the most common definition of U. What's your definition for U and why do you think it differs from the W there?

Comment: @glen-b - I knew there was a similar question, but I could not find it. Thank you very much!